# Issue in getting the comments from YAML using ruamel.yaml

Tags: get, yaml, comments, ruamel.yaml

Code:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# comments start
a: 52
# comment for a
b: 50
# comment for b
c: 50
# comment for c
d:
   # comment for d
   e: 60
   # comment for e
   f: 70
   # comment for f
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data.ca.comment)
print(data.ca.items)
```

Output:

```
[None, [CommentToken('# comments start\n', line: 0, col: 0)]]
{'a': [None, None, CommentToken('\n# comment for a\n', line: 2, col: 0), None], 'b': [None, None, CommentToken('\n# comment for b\n', line: 4, col: 0), None], 'c': [None, None, CommentToken('\n# comment for c\n', line: 6, col: 0), None], 'd': [None, None, None, [CommentToken('# comment for d\n', line: 8, col: 4)]]}
```

Question:

1. Why isn't it showing comments pertaining to the keys `e` and `f`?
2. What is the correct way to retrieve the comments based on the key say for example. How to get the comments for the key `e` ( `# comment for e`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruamel.yaml most comments are attached to the dict (or list) like
structure containing the key (or element) after which the comment
occurred.

To get to the comments following keys `e` and `f` you need to look at the dict
that is the value for `d`:

```
print(data['d'].ca.items)
print('comment post commment for "e":', repr(data['d'].ca.get('e', 2).value))
```

which gives:

```
{'e': [None, None, CommentToken('\n   # comment for e\n', line: 10, col: 3), None], 'f': [None, None, CommentToken('\n   # comment for f\n', line: 12, col: 3), None]}
comment post commment for "e": '\n   # comment for e\n'
```

Please note that the comment for `e` starts with a newline, indicating there is no end-of-line comment

Comment: Thanks Anthon, Generally comments are placed above the keys(elements) and why ruamel.yaml considers the comments after the key(As you said.. In ruamel.yaml most comments are attached to the dict (or list) like structure containing the key (or element) after which the comment occurred.).. Is my understanding wrong ?

Comment: These are essentially end of line comments extending to the next line, they get attached to the node that has been created after last parsing. `ruamel.yaml` was created to preserve comments during round-trip, i.e. load a YAML doc, update some value, dump the document and attaching to an already existing node was the easiest way to implement that.